# X into each of X

Tags: grammar

> Put the three petals into each of the hands of the three-handed
> statue.

Does this mean there's one petal on each of the hand? Or does it mean there are three petals on each hand? I think the former makes more sense, but I am wondering if I am somehow misusing the phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence could also mean you are to put all three into one hand, then move them to the second hand, then to the third hand. This meaning comes about because of the definite article "the", which refers to a specific set of three petals. If you leave out the article you need nine petals, three for each hand.

If there are three petals, one for each hand, it would be clearer to say "put a petal into each hand of the three-handed statue".